# Dynamic SQL : Create insert queries for tables having relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2017

I have 2 tables, `foo` and `bar`. `bar` holds a foreign key to `foo`, such as :

**foo**

```
id | some_data
-: | :--------
 1 | a
 2 | b
 3 | c
```

**bar**

```
id | id_foo | more_data
-: | -----: | :--------
 1 |      1 | d
 2 |      1 | e
 3 |      2 | f
 4 |      3 | g
 5 |      3 | h
 6 |      3 | i
```

I would like to dynamically create queries to insert elsewhere `foo` and `bar`.

For the table `foo`, it's pretty easily done :

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES (''', f.some_data, ''');') AS 'sql'
FROM foo f;
```

I'm getting this expected result :

```
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('c');
```

However, I'm stuck at generating the insert queries for the table that holds the foreign key.

I thought using 2 `UNION`s, one that gets the last inserted id, and the second one that uses this id to generate the queries for `bar` :

```
SELECT sql
FROM
(
    SELECT f.id AS 'id', CONCAT('INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES (''', f.some_data, ''');') AS 'sql'
    FROM foo f
    UNION
    SELECT f.id AS 'id', 'SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();' AS 'sql' -- Target will be MySQL
    FROM foo f
    UNION
    SELECT b.id_foo AS 'id', CONCAT('INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, ''', b.more_data, ''');') AS 'sql'
    FROM bar b
) s
ORDER BY s.id;
```

This gives me as output :

```
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'd');
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'e');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('a');
SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'f');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('b');
SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'g');
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'h');
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'i');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('c');
SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The order of the queries is wrong. It's producing first the queries for `bar`, then `foo`, then `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

It should be :

```
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('a');
SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'd');
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'e');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('b');
SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'f');
INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES ('c');
SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'g');
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'h');
INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, 'i');
```

How to ensure the correct order is respected ? I could play with the position of each query in the `UNION`, but I'm not sure if the orders of entries will be kept.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6433560894611b58e56d28574695487a) to play with

Comment: Have you considered allowing id insert and then just inserting the ids directly?  Then you don't have to worry about the foreign key relationships.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I unfortunatelly can't, the target is actually live and contains datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having three rows with the same id, and the order is not specified. You can just add a new column to specify the order:

```
SELECT sql
FROM
(
    SELECT f.id AS 'id', -1 AS seq, CONCAT('INSERT INTO new_foo (some_data) VALUES (''', f.some_data, ''');') AS 'sql'
    FROM foo f
    UNION
    SELECT f.id AS 'id', 0 AS seq, 'SET @last_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();' AS 'sql' -- Target will be MySQL
    FROM foo f
    UNION
    SELECT b.id_foo AS 'id', b.id AS seq, CONCAT('INSERT INTO new_bar (id_foo, more_data) VALUES (@last_id, ''', b.more_data, ''');') AS 'sql'
    FROM bar b
) s
ORDER BY s.id, s.seq;
```

Comment: Hehe I just have the same idea , but a bit different, using -1 for foo, 0 for last_insert_id and b.id for bar, to ensure that the order of bar is kept. I'll edit your answer and mark it as accepted